# Barcode Scanner in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avfoundation

I Used AV Foundation framework for barcode scanning functionality.

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;

input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (input) {
    [session addInput:input];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}

output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[session addOutput:output];

output.metadataObjectTypes = [output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

using delegete method i will get barcode result. i.e barcode number

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
    NSString *detectionString = nil;
    NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];

    for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
        for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
            if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
            {
                barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
                barcodeString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (barcodeString != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Barcode String: %@",barcodeString);
        }
        else
            label.text = @"(none)";
    }
}
```

Note: its working. but, the main reason, i'm not getting barcode number always. will you please help me for this issue.

Comment: Whats the exact problem you are face? you are not able to see the result or not getting result?

Comment: FYI: Here is a good tutorial about QR-Code scanning:  http://www.ama-dev.com/iphone-qr-code-library-ios-7/ It's almost the same procedure for any kind of code scan via AVFoundation

Answer (score 3):

Your delegate method looks fine, but you should add: videoGravity to your AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (prevLayer) and get the session started. Try adding these lines of code in the end of your first method:

```
prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:prevLayer];  
[session startRunning];
```

Comment: @Ravan Do you have created two different instances of prevLayer? Try change-ing all the prevLayer to _prevLayer in your first method.

Comment: I'm using _prevLayer object for AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer but its working same.

Comment: @Ravan i'll post my hole method to another method. For me it's working just fine

Comment: Ok thank you Alex, post it. i will check and inform you

Answer (score 1):

**I have used this open source project for Barcode scanning**..

it will surely help you:-

**LINK:**- https://github.com/jpwidmer/iOS7-BarcodeScanner

Answer (score 1):

Declare these objects in your .m (implementation) file:

```
AVCaptureSession *_session;
AVCaptureDevice *_device;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *_input;
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *_output;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *_prevLayer;

UIView *_highlightView;
UILabel *_label;
```

then add this method (which will be called by you):

```
-(void)readBarcode:(UIViewController*)myView
{ 
    _highlightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _highlightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    _highlightView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    _highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    [self.view addSubview:_highlightView];

    _label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40);
    _label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15 alpha:0.65];
    _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _label.text = @"(none)";
    [self.view addSubview:_label];

    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
    if (_input) {
        [_session addInput:_input];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_session addOutput:_output];

    _output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

    _prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    _prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];

    [_session startRunning];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_highlightView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_label];
}
```

and finally add the ***AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate***:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
    NSString *detectionString = nil;
    NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                              AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];

    for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
        for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
            if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
            {
                barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
                highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
                detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
                break;
            }
        }
if (detectionString != nil)
        {
            _label.text = detectionString;
            break;
        }
        else
            _label.text = @"(none)";
    }

    _highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at this [post](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx). You should read it carefully and also check the apple docs. And you can dowload the sample project from that post.

I do not know what problem you are facing exactly because your code looks fine. And may be the problem is you are scanning unsupportable barcodes like **DataMatrix**.

Please log your `detectionString` and see if every time you are getting value.

Answer (score 0):

In my Case i was using serial queues and hence was facing problems .
Always use Main queue like below
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];